# MySQL insert to bit(1) column via ODBC 5.2

Tags: mysql, oracle, odbc

I've searched and can't seem to find quite what I'm looking for.
I'm running a PL/SQL script in Oracle, and attempting to insert records into a table in MySQL via database link using MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver.

The link works fine, I can do complex queries in Oracle using it, and do various inserts and updates on records there.

Where it fails is in trying to insert a record into a MySQL table that has a column of type bit(1).

It is basically a cursor for loop, with the insert statement looking something like:

```
INSERT INTO "app_user"@mobileapi (USERNAME, VERSION, ACCOUNT_EXPIRED, ACCOUNT_LOCKED, PASSWD, PASSWORD_EXPIRED)
VALUES  (CU_rec.USERNAME, CU_rec.VERSION, CU_rec.ACCOUNT_EXPIRED, CU_rec.ACCOUNT_LOCKED, CU_rec.PASSWD, CU_rec.PASSWORD_EXPIRED)
```

Some of the target columns, like `ACCOUNT_EXPIRED`, `ACCOUNT_LOCKED`, etc. are the `bit(1)` columns in MySQL. Given that I can convert the data types in the cursor `CU_rec` to pretty much anything I want in Oracle, how can I get them inserted into the target? I've tried everything I can think of, and I just keep getting:

Error report:

```
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.10]Data too long for column 'ACCOUNT_EXPIRED' at row 1 {HY000,NativeErr = 1406}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MOBILEAPI
ORA-06512: at line 44
28500. 00000 -  "connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:"
*Cause:    The cause is explained in the forwarded message.
*Action:   See the non-Oracle system's documentation of the forwarded
           message.
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Mateusz :thanks for the formatting help on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Oracle's [default datatype conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/e10311/apa.htm) over ODBC; according to their own documentation they convert SQL_BINARY to a raw. Although not directly related, [Oracle's comparison of MySQL and Oracle within SQL Developer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#BABICBGE) also alludes to the fact that the automatic conversion from a MySQL bit is to an Oracle raw.

Extremely confusingly, [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-reference-datatypes.html) indicates that a bit is converted to a SQL_BIT or a SQL_CHAR, which implies that it *may* work in the other direction<sup>1</sup>.

According to [Microsoft's ODBC docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should, theoretically, be able to use the `CONVERT()` function to transform this into a character, which should, theoretically, be translatable by MySQL.

```
insert into some_table@some_db (bit_col)
values( {fn convert(some_col, SQL_CHAR)} );
```

Failing that there's another couple of options, but it does depend on what you're attempting to insert into the MySQL database from Oracle and what the datatype is in Oracle. For instance you could use the Oracle [`CAST()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613) function to convert between datatypes. For instance, the following would convert an integer to a binary double.

```
select cast(1 as binary_double) from dual
```

Unfortunately, you can't cast an integer to a raw, only a character or a rowid, so in order to convert to a raw you'd have to do the following:

```
select cast(to_char(1) as raw(1)) from dual
```

I've no idea whether MySQL will accept this but with some testing you should be able to work it out.

<sub>1. For clarity, I've never tried it in either direction.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, yes, I tried the binary_double casting, and it didn't work. I didn't get much further than that before I tried the string/EXECUTE IMMEDIATE solution, which worked.

Comment: Fair enough, it would be better to use plain SQL as you don't have to re-compile the statement you're executing each time but if performance isn't an issue then I don't suppose it matters much.

Answer (score 0):

Hah! I found a solution. Dropping it here in case it helps someone else. It's not pretty, but it works.

I used the old EXECUTE IMMEDIATE trick.

Basically, I created a variable `sql_stmt varchar2(4000)` and wrote code like:

```
sql_stmt := 'insert into "app_user"@mobileapi (USERNAME, VERSION, ACCOUNT_EXPIRED, ACCOUNT_LOCKED, CIPHER_PASSPHRASE, ENABLED, PASSWD, PASSWORD_EXPIRED) 
values ('''||CU_rec.USERNAME||'','||CU_rec.VERSION||', '||CU_rec.ACCOUNT_EXPIRED||', '||CU_rec.ACCOUNT_LOCKED||', '''||CU_rec.CIPHER_PASSPHRASE||''', '|| 
           CU_rec.ENABLED||', '''||CU_rec.PASSWD||''', '||CU_rec.PASSWORD_EXPIRED||')';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
```

Something like that anyway (the quotes might not line up, as I hacked this a bit from the actual code). Looking at the contents of sql_stmt, I get:

```
insert into "app_user"@mobileapi (USERNAME, VERSION, ACCOUNT_EXPIRED, ACCOUNT_LOCKED, CIPHER_PASSPHRASE, ENABLED, PASSWD,PASSWORD_EXPIRED) 
values ('user@email.com', 0, 0, 0, 'asdfastrwaebawavgansdhnsgjsjsh', 1, 'awercbcakwjerhcawuerawieubkahbewvkruh', 0)
```

The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE completes, and checking the target table, the values are there.

Possibly a crappy solution, but better than nothing.